# Must have a valid NSEntityDescription (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

### Bug

I started using CoreData for the first time today, but keep getting this bug.

`Thread 1: "An NSManagedObject of class 'MenuRPG.Inventory' must have a valid NSEntityDescription."`

However, I'm not really sure how I could fix this.

### What I've tried:

- Changing Entity module to `Current Product Module`
- Checking Entity name and class name
- Deleting my Entity and remaking it

But every time I try to add new info into my datamode, my app crashes and shows that error.

### My code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BagMenu: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Inventory.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var items:
        FetchedResults<Inventory>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text(item.name ?? "Unnamed")
                }
            }
            
            Button("Bake") {
                let breadPrefix = ["Half-baked", "Decent", "Perfect"]
                let breadTypes = ["rye", "sourdough", "bagel"]
                
                let chosenPrefix = breadPrefix.randomElement()!
                let chosenBread = breadTypes.randomElement()!
                
                let item = Inventory(context: self.moc)
                item.id = UUID()
                item.name = "\(chosenPrefix) \(chosenBread)"
                
                try? self.moc.save()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Could you modify your code to use `@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var items: FetchedResults<Inventory>` and try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you check if the following works:

#### Check the NSPersistentContainer name

- What is the `NSPersistentContainer` name you are using (check initializer)? Does it match the `xcdatamodeld` file name?

#### Check the App Code

- It is very important to initialise `PersistenceController` before using it.
- So that the entities are loaded.
  If you are using the SwiftUI App life cycle then check the following:

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestCoreDataApp: App {
    //This is very important to initialise `PersistenceController` before using it. So that the entities are loaded.
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Clear Cache:

- Xcode caches the entity classes and sometimes that could cause issues.
- Try Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder (Command Shift K). (or remove contents of DerivedData folder).
- Delete the app on the simulator / device
- Quit Xcode and re-open and run.

#### Sample Project:

- It might help to use the sample CoreData Project if you are new to CoreData.
- Xcode > New Project > Check the CoreData checkbox

#### Documentation

It might help to go through CoreData documentation. Yes it can be time consuming but it might help in the long run.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata
- Sample Xcode project

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm still getting the same error when using that code, and I'm currently trying to add CoreData to an existing project. Do you know what else I might be able to try? I apologize for the follow-up question.

Comment: Xcode caches the entity classes and sometimes that could cause issues, try Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder (Command Shift K). Delete the app on the simulator / device, quit Xcode and then try again

Comment: I cleaned my build folder, uninstalled my app, and reinstalled it, but I still kept getting the same error.

Comment: Does it seem to work with the sample project? If so could you have a look at `PersistenceController` struct from the sample project and see how things are initialised and loaded as opposed to your code?

Comment: What is the NSPersistentContainer name you are using? Does it match the `xcdatamodeld` file name?

Comment: I have updated the answer with more possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

some updates if you manually setting up the NSPersistentContainer and missing the PersistenceController here is update from Paul Hudson for Xcode 14.2

**change "Main" to your "FileName" of your file of the .xcdatamodeld**
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-configure-core-data-to-work-with-swiftui

Took me 2 days to find out the answer!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34263456)